# Install opencv on visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have installed open cv and have configured all the path variables as mentioned in step by step procedure.

I tried a sample program to verify whether my installations are correct. I have mentioned all the path for include files, library files and additional path variables in visual studio 2013.

I am getting error "Cannot open opencv2/core.hpp no such file or directory"

When i check the location of the include file under opencv2 folder there is no such file. But i can see the same in github. If i branch out and download the same from github again in my local I cannot see the core.hpp.

Answer (score 0):

Got answer for this issue... This is because from version 3 openCV needs only couple of lib files to be associated with additional library dependency.. Earlier we need to have multiple lib files for the same...